# Count subgroup not total row on jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I try to show the numbers of subgroup in the main group with jqgrid

```
like : ---->main group (2) items
           ------> subgroup1 (1) items
                   -----------> item 1
           ------> subgroup2 (2) items
                   -----------> item 1
                   -----------> item 2
```

with the property GroupText it's possible ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use summaryTpl to display the count of the group.

For more info refer the [documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/grouping/#colmodel-options)

Demo [here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/grouping/summary/index.html)